problem with trying to compile ps4 11.50 webkit on debian linux
-- Enabled features:
--  ENABLE_ACCELERATED_2D_CANVAS ............ ON
--  ENABLE_CREDENTIAL_STORAGE                 ON
--  ENABLE_DRAG_SUPPORT ..................... ON
--  ENABLE_GEOLOCATION                        ON
--  ENABLE_GLES2 ............................ OFF
--  ENABLE_GTKDOC                             OFF
--  ENABLE_ICONDATABASE ..................... ON
--  ENABLE_INTROSPECTION                      ON
--  ENABLE_JIT .............................. ON
--  ENABLE_MANX_POINTER_POISON                ON
--  ENABLE_MEMORY_SAMPLER ................... ON
--  ENABLE_MINIBROWSER                        OFF
--  ENABLE_OPENGL ........................... ON
--  ENABLE_PLUGIN_PROCESS_GTK2                ON
--  ENABLE_SPELLCHECK ....................... ON
--  ENABLE_TOUCH_EVENTS                       ON
--  ENABLE_VIDEO ............................ ON
--  ENABLE_WAYLAND_TARGET                     OFF
--  ENABLE_WEB_AUDIO ........................ ON
--  ENABLE_X11_TARGET                         ON
--  USE_LIBHYPHEN ........................... ON
--  USE_LIBNOTIFY                             ON
--  USE_SYSTEM_MALLOC ....................... OFF
-- Configuring done (14.1s)
CMake Error at Source/WebKit2/PlatformGTK.cmake:823 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "GObjectDOMBindings" of target
  "webkit2gtkinjectedbundle" does not exist.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Source/cmake/WebKitMacros.cmake:5 (include)
  Source/WebKit2/CMakeLists.txt:795 (WEBKIT_INCLUDE_CONFIG_FILES_IF_EXISTS)


CMake Error at Source/WebKit2/CMakeLists.txt:803 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "WebCore" of target "WebKit2" does not exist.


-- Generating done (0.6s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no Playstation port for Linux, your logs show building the GTK port. Could you elaborate on what you want?

I have solved it when I installed the webkit from https://www.playstation.com/en-us/oss/ps4/webkit/ i was trying it on 11.50 (A) i just had to install (B) and i compiled it with small code adjustments
